# Show that the associated matrix is $PAP^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, change-of-basis, free-modules

Let $\eta \in \operatorname{End}_{R}(R^n)$ and let $A$ be the associated matrix of $\eta$ with respect to the basis $(e_1, \dots e_n)$. Let $f_i = \sum p_{i,j}e_j$ where the matrix $P=(p_{i,j}) \in GL_n(R)$. Show that  $PAP^{-1}$ is the associated matrix of the basis $(f_1 \dots f_n)$.

$\underline{My \space attempt:}$

$$\eta(f_i) = \eta\left(\sum_{j=1}^n p_{i,j}e_j \right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \eta(p_{i,j} e_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n p_{i,j} \eta(e_j)$$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^n p_{i,j} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} e_k \right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n(p_{i,j}a_{i,k})e_k$$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n (p_{i,j}a_{i,k}p_{i,j}^{-1})p_{i,j}e_k$$

From here I see that I am very close but I'm not sure how to turn that $p_{i,j}e_k$ into the $f_{k}$ because the sum includes all the other terms. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The $i,j$ element of $P^{-1}$ is not the inverse of $p_{i,j}$.

Comment: Are you sure of the formulæ in this question? Normally the coordinates of the $f-i$s  in basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ should be column vectors in $P$, not row vectors.

Comment: Yeah I double checked what I have written is exactly what is in the book.  Perhaps its a typo on the books part?

Comment: I think $p^{-1}_{i,j}$ is supposed to mean the $i,j$ element of $P^{-1}$, rather than $(p_{ij})^{-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the notation $p^{-1}_{ij}$ to refer to the $i,j$ entry of $P^{-1}$, which is what I suspect your book did.

We could finish your proof as follows:
$$
\eta(f_i) = \eta \left( \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} e_{j}\right) = \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} \eta(e_{j})\\
= \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk}e_{k}\right) = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n p_{ij}a_{jk} e_k
\\= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n p_{ij}a_{jk} \left(\sum_{\ell=1}^n p^{-1}_{k\ell}f_{\ell}\right)
= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n p_{ij}a_{jk}p^{-1}_{k\ell} f_\ell
$$
Now, it suffices to note that $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n  p_{ij}a_{jk}p^{-1}_{k\ell}$ is indeed the $(\ell,i)$ of the matrix $PAP^{-1}$.